# Download document from mysql database

Tags: php, web

I have uploaded a file into MySQL database but while retrieving I am having aproblem.

**download.php**

```
<?php

    $host="localhost";
                $username="root";
                $password="";
$db_name="application";

$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("Your Connection is in error");

$a =$_GET['contactid'];

$query = "SELECT filename,filetype,filesize,filecontent FROM contact WHERE contactid = '$a' ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($filename, $filetype, $filesize, $filecontent) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-length: $filesize");
header("Content-type: $filetype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
echo $filecontent;
exit;
?>
```

$a which I get from the previous screen is not working. Instead if I give contactid = 18.. file is getting downloaded.

**previous screen.php**

```
$GET =mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT contactid,groupname,firstname,lastname,mobile1,mobile2,email1,email2,city,country,designation,companyname,address1,address2,district,pincode,website,others,filename FROM contact WHERE contactid='$a'"));
$contactid   = $GET['contactid'];
$filename  = $GET['filename'];
<a href='download.php?contactid=".$contactid."'><?php echo $filename;?>    </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href='download.php?contactid=".$contactid."'><?php echo $filename;?>    </a>
```

Above statement using two php variables `$contactid` and `$filename`. You have `echo` the `$filename` but forgot to echo `$contactid`. If the above statement not inside the `PHP` tags. Then it should be,

```
<a href='download.php?contactid=<?php echo $contactid ?>'><?php echo $filename;?>    </a>
```

If it's inside the `PHP` tags then it should be like,

```
echo "<a href='download.php?contactid=".$contactid."'>".$filename."</a>";
```

Comment: by the way +10 from my side because you pointed out correct things.

Comment: Thanks, Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Alok I have changed but still same problem i'm getting empty document downloaded. In download.php the contact id value is not accepted

Comment: Try this in download.php `var_dump($_GET['contactid'])` what are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 "...... where contactid='".$a."'";
```